# Double orthogonal complement in general finite-dimensional inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

I am trying to show that if $V$ is a finite-dimensional inner product space, then for any $X \subseteq V$ we have $(X ^{\perp})^{\perp} = \langle X \rangle$, the subspace of $V$ generated by $X$.

It is easy to show that $X \subseteq (X^{\perp})^{\perp}$ and therefore since orthogonal complements are subspaces of $V$, it easily follows that $\langle X \rangle \subseteq (X^{\perp})^{\perp}$. But I am struggling to show the reverse inclusion.

Any pointers??

Comment: Show that $\langle X \rangle$ and $X^{\perp \perp}$ have the same dimension

Comment: Note that $X^{\perp}=\langle X\rangle^{\perp}$, and so it is enough to prove this when $X$ is a subspace. In this case there is an inclusion (as you know) and equality of dimensions.

Comment: Where is the equality of dimensions coming from?

Comment: @Anonmath101 I'd say that's for you to find out :). Do you know the relationship between $\dim(U)$ and $\dim(U^\perp)$ for a subspace $U$ of $V$?